# SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) not filling DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to retrieve records from a database in a WPF application written in C#. I'm using the SQL data reader and it appears to connect fine but the following is giving me a NullReferenceException:

```
        if (isString == true)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PartNumber FROM LoanerItems", loanersConnection);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatable);

            for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count - 1; i ++)
            {
                passBackRecords[i] = datatable.Rows[i].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Again it would appear that I'm connecting to the database but if I run through the debugger the datatable doesn't appear to be filled.

My connection string in case it might help:

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        scsb.DataSource = "LLOYD2\\";
        scsb.InitialCatalog = "LoanersTest";
        scsb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        scsb.ConnectTimeout = 30;
```

I'm currently using a test database with two records in it instead of the finalized database. I've tried using the Transact-SQL Editor and the records appear just fine.

*EDIT:

After intializing passBackRecords the following started throwing an ArguementOutOfRange exception:

```
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanerItems", loanersConnection);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatable);
            for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                passBackRecords[i] = datatable.Rows[i]["BCPartNumber"].toString;
            }
```

I've tried both:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

and:

```
for (int i = 1; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
```

But neither seems to work.

```
datatable.Rows.Count;
```

shows that there are two rows in the datatable.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: Are you sure that `isString == true`?

Comment: I'd wager that it's `passBackRecords` that's null. In which line exactly to you get the Exception?

Comment: you're code looks fine. Do you have data in your database?

Comment: What do you expect is the result of calling `datatable.Rows[i].ToString()`? I bet it is not at all what you think

Comment: Yep, `datatable.Rows[i].ToString()` is going to give you `System.Data.DataRow`.  Not the value, you need a reference to the column as well.  `datatable.Rows[i]["theColumn"].ToString();` BUT yes, it looks as though `passBackRecords` is null, thus causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if zero rows were returned, the `DataTable` wouldn't be `null`. However, there is one place in this line:

```
passBackRecords[i] = datatable.Rows[i].ToString();
```

that will fail -when `passBackRecords` is `null`. Another possible location is this:

```
.Rows[i].ToString();
```

if the value in the row is `null` you'd also get a `NullReferenceException` when calling `ToString()`. But I'd **almost** put money on the fact that you've not yet initialized `passBackRecords`.

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to initialize passBackRecords. Thank you for that one. I'm still unsure how to correctly read from the datatable as I found 

`Rows[i].ToString();`

Doesn't actually return that data in the row.

Comment: @ZachSmith, instead of using `Rows[i].ToString()` use `Rows[i] as string` so it doesn't fail.

Comment: Rows[i].ToString() will only give you a string representation of the Row Object.  To access specific Columns of your data you need to do this Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString();

Comment: Made a quick edit to the main post. I'm getting an ArguementOutOfRange exception now.

Comment: @Zach, how did you initialize the passBackRecords?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud `private List<string> passBackRecords = new List<string>();` It appears to be working fine. The ArguementOutOfRange exception is on the datatable.